# Git Output Console in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: visual-studio-mac

[Git Output Console used in Visual Studio Code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NmHQ.png)

Do we have Git Output console in Visual Studio for MAC. I have used similar one in Visual Studio Code but I cannot find anything similar in VS for MAC.
How I can see this feature in Visual Studio for Mac.

If I can view the GIT commands that are called internally by the editor. That would really help me to learn GIT command effectively.

Any help on this regard is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing like this exists in Visual Studio for Mac.